# Can I swap out cinch clamps on a piece of PEX pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, pex

I used a cinch clamp to fit a PEX pipe with a valve. Turns out the valve is too small, so I would like to replace it.

Is it OK to just remove the old clamp, put in the new valve, and put a new cinch clamp on the exact same spot on the pipe as the old clamp?

I'm worried that spot will be flawed in some way because it already had a clamp on it, but there's very little pipe for me to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool made just to remove cinch clamps from PEX. After removing inspect the pipe for cuts and nicks if there is none you should be ok. If the pipe is damaged you could try cutting the pipe back some install a coupling and replace the bad end

Comment: A flathead screwdriver can be used to remove a cinch ring. You can also cut through the actual crimped section with a hacksaw or a small cutting wheel on a rotary tool ie Dremel